# Проблема цикла в шаблонизаторе

Tags: php, циклы, шаблонизаторы

Доброго времени суток. Использую шаблонизатор [Fenom](https://github.com/fenom-template/fenom/blob/master/docs/ru/tags/foreach.md) и в него вывожу массив с настройками шаблона в том числе и список боковой панели(sidebar). Где хранятся данные о вкладке. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так как он находится в массиве под массивом то код:

```
{foreach $sidebar as $key => $value}
     <div>{$key} : {$value}</div>
{/foreach}
```

Получаю

```
0 : Array 
1 : Array 
2 : Array 
3 : Array
```

Comment: Помогите решить данную проблему и что мне сделать с этим. Массив данных получаю через:
mysqli_fetch_all c параметром MYSQLI_NUM

Comment: Не совсем ясно что вас не устраивает, вывод вполне логичный, выводит ключ и значение, значение это массив, хотите из этого массива что то получить, обращайтесь к ключам массива. С шаблонизатором не работал, но судя из документации - `{$value.name}` или `{$value['name']}`, выведет название категории из массива.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще перебирайте и вложенные массивы для получения результата.

```
{foreach $sidebar as $key => $value}
     {foreach $sidebar as $_key => $_val}
        {$_key} : {$_val}
     {/foreach}
{/foreach}
```

так же как и в php

```
{foreach $sidebar as $key => $value}
     {$value['id']}
{/foreach}
```

см. доку https://github.com/fenom-template/fenom/blob/master/docs/ru/syntax.md#%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8B

Comment: Данный код работает. Но выдает просто все ключи и значения: [ссылка](http://pastebin.com/tZ50akNy)
Можете подсказать как взять определенной ключ и его значения. Например id